# Python `no module pip.__main__;` error when trying to install a module

Tags: python, pip

I am getting the following error on my Raspberry Pi: `No module named pip__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed`

When I type in to the terminal: `sudo python3 -m pip install mp3play`

What is causing this and how can I fix it so that I can install the module `mp3play`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pip is not only a standalone executable, it is also a python module.

In fact in the python docs it directly recommends using the `-m` syntax for installing a package using pip.

See https://docs.python.org/3.5/installing/index.html#basic-usage:

> The standard packaging tools are all designed to be used from the command line.
>
> The following command will install the latest version of a module and its dependencies from the Python Packaging Index:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install SomePackage
> ```

My guess would have been that your system's `pip` (the executable) was being shadowed by the python2 version of the `pip` executable. But it sounds like you don't have pip (the module) installed such that your python3 executable can find it, so you may need to reinstall pip (the module) specifically.

For that use `python3 -m ensurepip`  ([docs for ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#command-line-interface)) which will install pip if it is not present from the persepctive of your python3 interpreter.

The other issue could be that it's finding a file, executable or directory called `pip` in your current directory, and it is trying to treat that `pip` as a module, and it is not in fact a module.

If it's not that I'm not sure. But it is definitely not because pip is not a module.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and none of the previous answers solved it for me.

The error appeared when I uninstalled and reinstalled python to my PC. As it appears the previous existing version of pip wasn't completely removed and when I was trying to import it with `python -m pip install package` it was actually trying to call the previous version.

To solve it first **manually delete** the pip folders in the following locations:

```
C:\Users\username\pip
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pip
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python**\lib\site-packages\pip***
C:\Python**\pip
```

Then download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Finally, navigate to the folder where you downloaded it and run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

This procedure should reinstall pip and fix the issue.

Answer (score 5):

`pip` is a standalone executable. If `pip` if in your path, you can just execute

```
pip install mp3play
```

If `pip` is not in your path, then you need to navigate to the directory where `pip` is located and then execute the above.

If needed, add `sudo` to the command.

The precise error you are encountered is due to `pip` being a package, but `-m` is used for executing modules.

EDIT: `pip` also comes with several helpful alias functions that point to different Python installs. In general, `pip` points to your main Python install (the one you enter when simply executing `python`), `pipV` where `V` is a number such as `2` or `3` adds the install to your primary Python of version `V` (`pip3` adds to your `python3` environment). Finally there is `pipV.S` where `V` is the same as before and `S` is the subversion. For instance `pip3.4` installs for Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I found that an old pip directory was left over from a python 2.7 install, at `C:\Users\my-username\pip`.  This was causing python to try to load pip from there and fail.

I removed that directory and my error has just become `No module named pip`.

I haven't solved the problem yet, but I'm working through it at http://bugs.python.org/issue29586

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

This can occur when the existing pip module may get affected while upgrading it.

You might observe in `site-packages`, that any required file/ folder has been renamed with a leading `~`, say `pip` changed to `~ip` or the subfolders with a leading `~`.

So, while referring to the module pip, if fails to find the required executable files.

The reason this happens is [read](https://discuss.python.org/t/pip-list-has-packages-whose-name-starts-with-a-hypen/2047/3):

> When uninstalling a package, pip will now rename it in place to a name
> that cannot be imported, and once it has confirmed that everything
> will succeed (including installing new versions if it’s doing an
> upgrade), only then will it delete those folders. If something fails,
> it renames them back.

### Solution:

In addition to the solution [by @Djib2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972544/8126119), alternatively you can use to fresh install the *pip* module:

```
py <-version> -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

where `<-version>` is an optional argument and can be replaced with a version of python you have been facing issues with say, `-3.8`.

Python comes with an *ensurepip* module, which can install pip in a Python environment. This would install the pip module which was initially packaged with the version of python you have been using.

Post which you can run the upgrade command to port pip to the newer version.

```
py <-version> -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

You can append the `--user` option if you face any `EnvironmentError` due to permission.

Reference:

1. [pip installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)
2. [pip how to remove incorrectly installed package with a leading dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname)