# What's with this "d:\Python26\python.exe: pip is a package and cannot be directly executed"

Tags: python, pip

So we currently use python 2.6 for production, and I just installed `pip` but couldn't get any output from cmd on windows 10. Then I tried with `python -m pip ...` then I got `d:\Python26\python.exe: pip is a package and cannot be directly executed`, it's quite annoying so how do I fix this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import pip; print pip.__file__"`? Maybe something from your working directory shadows installed package.

Comment: looks like it's all right: `d:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.pyc`

Comment: And what is `python -c "import pip; print pip.__version__"`?

Comment: it's `9.0.1`, maybe 9.0.1 doesn't support 2.6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute an installed Python package as a script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050120/execute-an-installed-python-package-as-a-script)

Comment: It looks like it's forbidden in Python 2.6. Try: `python -m pip.__main__`.

Comment: Now it's working! Thanks a lot!! Any idea why `pip` alone not working in command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python \`no module pip.\_\_main\_\_;\` error when trying to install a module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664082/python-no-module-pip-main-error-when-trying-to-install-a-module)

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is a standalone executable, not package. After using `get-pip.py` for installing pip, you should have pip executable in `d:\Python26\`. Go to that folder to check if pip is there:

```
cd d:\Python26\
pip freeze
```

Then you need to add pip to your PATH: https://superuser.com/a/949573

Comment: There's no pip executable in `d:\Python26\`, it's in `d:\Python26\Scripts`. And yes I've already added that path into my PATH

Comment: In that case you should be able to use `pip freeze` anywhere in shell. Also restart computer to update PATH (you can also find a way to do without restart, but in case with windows restarting is always better :D)