# Error with pip install: "No moduel named pip.__main__"

Tags: python-3.x

On my computer (windows 8.1) there is python 3.4.
When I try to install module with `pip install` the code that I use is:

```
py -m pip install ...
```

But the command line returns the following error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly exec
uted
```

Comment: May be it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664082/python-no-module-pip-main-error-when-trying-to-install-a-module/41731443

Answer (score 0):

Pip is just not a standalone executable. It is a python module.
So as a matter of fact you can do this (Tested with numpy, worked correctly as wanted):

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

Well, you should see the documentation on [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/installing/index.html).
I did mention that Pip is a  standalone executable. If it is in you path then you can also do this:

```
pip install numpy
```

Make sure python is in your path.