# pip how to remove incorrectly installed package with a leading dash: "-pkgname"

Tags: python, windows, pip

After running `pip freeze` I noticed the following warning on top of the list:

```
WARNING: Could not parse requirement: -atplotlib
```

So I checked the installed packages using `pip list`, and indeed the following is considered a package:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
-atplotlib      3.0.3
```

I assume I probably had a typo when installing/upgrading `matplotlib`, which led to the aforementioned "package" being installed.

But I am not able to remove it as `pip uninstall -atplotlib` is read as a command and returns the following error:

```
No such option: -a
```

I found the following folders:

```
C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~atplotlib

C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info
```

Is it safe, and sufficient, to remove them?

Comment: How did you find the relevant folders? i.e. C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~atplotlib. Is there some python code (from os or sys library) to find this directory? I am asking because I did not install anaconda. I installed Python through VS Code (which downloads python from the MS store)

Comment: Running pip list actually also mentions the directory.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

EDIT: According to [this link](https://discuss.python.org/t/pip-list-has-packages-whose-name-starts-with-a-hypen/2047/3), provided by Lawrence in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64939049/3284713)

> looking for and deleting the incorrectly named folders in your
> `site-package` directory should solve the issue.

***If this is not sufficient, continue the cleaning as explained below.***

Searching for the name of the broken package (without the leading dash) allowed me to find the following two folders:

> C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages~atplotlib

> C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages~atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info

Following Hoefling's comment (below)

I checked the `SOURCES.txt` file in the egg-info directory `%dir%/~atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt`. Went through the list of paths in this file and made sure all paths listed did not contained `~`. Then I renamed the directory `~atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info` into `atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info` (removed the tilde `~`).
Finally, I ran `pip uninstall atplotlib`, which prompted the following:

> Uninstalling atplotlib-3.0.3:
> Would remove:
> C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info
> C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib
> C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pylab.py

Proceeding with the removal solved the issue (the warning disappeared and the package is not anymore on the package list.

Comment: The problem is that you have not removed all the installed files by doing that and since you have removed the `egg-info` dir, you don't have the info about the installed files (file `~atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt`). You should go through the list of paths in this file and make sure all paths listed there don't contain `~` and match the paths on disk (renaming if necessary). Then rename the only directory `~atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info` to remove the tilde (e.g. `atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info`), then `pip uninstall atplotlib`.

Comment: Looking at the `matplotlib` installation, you should have `mpl_toolkits` dir and `pylab.py` module remaining in the `C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` dir (maybe also with tilde prepended). Removing those should complete the cleanup.

Comment: @hoefling Hi, thanks for the instructions. I can easily restore the two folders if that helps with the clean up process (I backed them up)

Comment: @removing the `~` from the folder and running `pip uninstall atplotlib` I get the following: `Uninstalling atplotlib-3.0.3: Would remove: C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\atplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7.egg-info,    C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib,      C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pylab.py` should I proceed?

Comment: Did you check the `SOURCES.txt` contents? If it's only listing these paths, then it's safe to proceed.

Comment: @hoefling the sources.txt has an infinite amount of paths (It lists every file in every subolder from what I see). The ones that start with `lib/` are: `matplotlib`,`mpl_toolkits` and `pylab.py`. The others are the following: `extern/`, `examples/`,`doc/`,`LICENSE/`,`src/`,`tools/`,`tutorials/`.

Comment: I do not have a egg-info, but a ~-p-20.2.3.dist-info\. Did not find a sources.txt either.

Comment: Be aware that you may have **many** files named `SOURCES.txt`. In my case,
`$ find / -name SOURCES.txt 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
gave `105`.

Comment: On my end I had to remove the folder instead of doing `pip uninstall <pkg>`

Answer (score 60):

It is safe to delete the offending folder(s) from your `site-packages` directory.

More info below ([source](https://discuss.python.org/t/pip-list-has-packages-whose-name-starts-with-a-hypen/2047/3)):

> When uninstalling a package, pip will now rename it in place to a name
> that cannot be imported, and once it has confirmed that everything
> will succeed (including installing new versions if it’s doing an
> upgrade), only then will it delete those folders. If something fails,
> it renames them back.
>
> Previously, it would copy the entire contents to another directory,
> and potentially another drive, and then copy them back if it needed.
> So this change is a significant performance improvement, especially
> for packages with a lot of files in them.
>
> What you’re seeing here is that the deletion failed for some reason -
> perhaps pip crashed? - and so the directories were not removed. I
> thought pip ignored them completely, but perhaps something else
> changed since I tested that?
>
> The directories are safe to delete.

Comment: Link is golden.

Comment: How can I delete all offending folder(s), where are they located?

Comment: On windows, check C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

Comment: "perhaps pip crashed?" -- in my case, I was running a virtualenv in WSL, and VSCode in remote mode was locking a couple of my packages when I tried to update. This caused the artifacts to remain in my `site-packages` folder. Deleting the offending folders worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I received the following error myself, after executing:
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user`

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)

1. I went to the file specification within the C:\
2. Located the -ip (it was located at the top) and I deleted it.
3. Executed the code again

Results:

> Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\GhostFace\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (21.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do `rm -rf atplotlib`  after removing `~` character as beginning of the file name.

```
$ pip freeze | grep atplotlib
$ cd /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
$ mv \~ atplotlib atplotlib
$ pip freeze | grep atplotlib
atplotlib ==3.0.3
$  pip uninstall atplotlib
WARNING: Skipping atplotlib as it is not installed.
$ rm -rf atplotlib
```