# Unable to uninstall package named `-umpy`

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, uninstallation

Runnig `py -m pip list` in windows powershell, produces:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
-umpy           1.15.4
autogui         0.1.8
beautifulsoup4  4.8.0
cycler          0.10.0
et-xmlfile      1.0.1
...and so on
```

as you can see there is a package named `-umpy` which must be some kind of a *computer hiccup*.

Now I want to uninstall this package but the `py -m pip uninstall -umpy` command does not work since it thinks I am trying to pass an argument..

**Does anybody know how to get rid of this package?**

I have already tried various escapes:

```
>> py -m pip uninstall /-umpy
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '/-umpy'

>> py -m pip uninstall `-umpy
Usage:
  C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe -m pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe -m pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: -u

>> py -m pip uninstall \-umpy
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '\\-umpy'
Hint: It looks like a path. File '\-umpy' does not exist.

>> py -m pip uninstall "-umpy"
Usage:
  C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe -m pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe -m pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: -u
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
py -m pip uninstall -- -umpy
```

Double dashes separate options from non-options; used exactly in case like this.

BTW, I don't think `-umpy` is a real package. It seems it's a leftover from an unsuccessful uninstallation of a package `numpy`.

It could be you need to remove its directories manually. To do that, type `py -m pip list -v` to get a list of all installed modules together with their installation location and then simply delete the corresponding folders.

Comment: I had exactly the same invalid package. I also thought it was somehow an invalid name for numpy. I wonder if there's something funky happening with numpy's installer 

Comment: @xaviersjs Common problem with `pip`, not related to `numpy`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56973015/7976758

Comment: If I try that then I get ```WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\users\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages) ERROR: Invalid requirement: '-umpy' ```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
print((bytes(subprocess.check_output(['pip', 'uninstall', '-umpy'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)).decode()))
```

To automate it in a python script.