# PIP3 | WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -ertifi 2019.11.28

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.6, warnings, uninstallation

I recently uninstalled all pip3 the pip3 packages installed in my local system.

Now, whenever I type `pip3 freeze`, this warning pops up:

```
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -ertifi 2019.11.28 
(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages): Parse error at "'-ertifi='": Expected W:(abcd...)
```

How do I get rid of this warning.

I tried doing `brew reinstall python3` as this would reinstall python3 along with pip3 but it doesn't seem to work.

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip how to remove incorrectly installed package with a leading dash: "-pkgname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+leading+dash

Comment: @phd this is useful, however, it's clear that the package in question is `certifi`, which begs the question, how did it get installed so? Why is it `-ertifi` and not `certifi`? I've ran into same problem with a virtualenv created `poetry` and solved it by nuking and re-creating the virtual env.

Comment: @Ferran: my recommendation: go to your `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and clean it up manually, then reinstall packaged you need. 

Comment: @DimaTisnek You were right. The package name had somehow been misspelled. I reinstalled and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was getting that same error but for a different package:

`WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -niso8601 8.0.0 (...) venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages): Parse error at "'-niso860'": Expected W:(abcd...)`

It turned out to be a missing letter in my first package! I needed to have "aniso8601==7.0.0"  I literally did a freeze from a different venv that had that same package I needed, copied and pasted into the requirements.txt in the new project's folder. The requirements.txt file in the new project then installed successfully.

TL;DR: My requirements.txt file had a typo.

Comment: I see this error crop up for quite a few users, I'm not convinced it's always user error. I'm pretty sure I had a working venv, that broke "all by itself" (possibly python or distutils or pip update) and suddenly refused to work. ‍♂️

Comment: @DimaTisnek, honestly I'm not sure either.

Comment: Think this happens when you pip uninstall, this leaves behind ~folders in your site-packages, deleting these resolves the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I got into similar problem after I have upgraded my pip under windows from version 20.1.1 to version 20.2.3

It turned out that old version of pip was renaming folders that it could not delete, replacing first letter with tilda ~

The new version of pip counts this tilda as hyphen - I don't know why

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this. Using pip3 show <package-name> I was able to locate the folder '~andas' that 'pip3 freeze' was breaking on. I changed dir to the path it showed (~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages) and was able to delete all of the folders that started with ~ and pip3 freeze worked again.

Comment: Not specific to Windows, and whereas getting `ls` to show such a subdirectory name on my linux fails to find it, I could indeed find it using `find` just there under site-packages and get a peaceful `pip freeze` after removing it. I wonder if it's safe to remove all those ~ prefixed directories there.