# Upgrading pip can leave artefact installations with a leading ~ (tilde) this gives an erroneous error on using pip. How is this fixed?

Tags: python, pip, warnings

As in [WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) How do I fix this and what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442661/warning-ignoring-invalid-distribution-ip-c-python39-lib-site-packages-how-d) which is not a duplicate.

The warning message 'WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip...' is the sign that this is happening.

This is referenced in https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9417

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63890160/7976758

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to manually remove the directories ~ip and ~ip-m.m.p.dist-info (where m.m.p is the version number that was upgraded) from the site-packages directory.