# Heroku Could not generate requirement for distribution -lotly 2.7.0

Tags: heroku

Hi I am having some error when I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku. 
When I pip freeze>requirements.txt, I am getting this error:

"WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -lotly 2.7.0 (c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-lotly=='": Expected W:(abcd...)"

Can anyone help me out? thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip how to remove incorrectly installed package with a leading dash: "-pkgname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this error by deleting this module from the site-packages directory. from your question above, it looks like the module is present in c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages .

you can do a sanity check by using pip freeze .

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while I was trying to do "*pip freeze > requirements.txt*"

```
Could not generate requirement for distribution -eportlab3.5 ....
```

There should be a corrupt file on the site-packages folder similar to '*~eportlab-3.5.50.dist-info*' OR '*~eportlab*'. Delete it manually and run the same command. It should work.