# Package "-ensorflow-gpu' installed in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I printed a list of packages in my python installation when I spotted this package "-ensorflow-gpu". I tried uninstalling it but pip didn't work.

I used
`py -3.7 -m pip uninstall "-ensorflow-gpu"` and `py -3.7 -m pip uninstall -ensorflow-gpu` , the error for both times was

```
Usage:
  C:\Users\Shaleen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  C:\Users\Shaleen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: -e
```

My question is should I leave it alone or should I clean install python again?

Edit:

it's not a typo , there literally is a package called -ensorflow-gpu

I have attached my list of packages for reference

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ------------------
-ensorflow-gpu           2.3.0
absl-py                  0.10.0
aio-pika                 6.4.1
aiormq                   3.2.2
astunparse               1.6.3
attrs                    20.2.0
backcall                 0.2.0
beautifulsoup4           4.9.1
bs4                      0.0.1
cachetools               4.1.1
certifi                  2020.6.20
cffi                     1.14.0
chardet                  3.0.4
click                    7.1.2
colorama                 0.4.3
cryptography             3.0
cycler                   0.10.0
Cython                   0.29.14
DAWG-Python              0.7.2
decorator                4.4.2
deeppavlov               0.11.0
dill                     0.3.2
dm-tree                  0.1.5
docopt                   0.6.2
fastapi                  0.47.1
future                   0.18.2
gast                     0.3.3
google-auth              1.21.1
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.1
google-pasta             0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0
grpcio                   1.32.0
h11                      0.9.0
h5py                     2.10.0
idna                     2.8
importlib-metadata       1.7.0
importlib-resources      3.0.0
ipykernel                5.3.4
ipython                  7.16.1
ipython-genutils         0.2.0
jedi                     0.17.2
joblib                   0.16.0
jupyter-client           6.1.6
jupyter-core             4.6.3
Keras                    2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing      1.1.2
kiwisolver               1.2.0
lxml                     4.5.2
Markdown                 3.2.2
matplotlib               3.3.0
multidict                4.7.6
nltk                     3.4.5
numpy                    1.18.0
oauthlib                 3.1.0
opt-einsum               3.3.0
overrides                2.7.0
pamqp                    2.3.0
pandas                   0.25.3
parso                    0.7.1
pickleshare              0.7.5
Pillow                   7.2.0
pip                      20.1.1
promise                  2.3
prompt-toolkit           3.0.5
protobuf                 3.13.0
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pycparser                2.20
pydantic                 1.3
Pygments                 2.6.1
pymorphy2                0.8
pymorphy2-dicts          2.4.393442.3710985
pymorphy2-dicts-ru       2.4.404381.4453942
pyOpenSSL                19.1.0
pyparsing                2.4.7
pyTelegramBotAPI         3.6.7
python-dateutil          2.8.1
pytz                     2019.1
pywin32                  228
PyYAML                   5.3.1
pyzmq                    19.0.1
requests                 2.22.0
requests-oauthlib        1.3.0
rsa                      4.6
ruamel.yaml              0.15.100
rusenttokenize           0.0.5
sacremoses               0.0.35
scikit-learn             0.21.2
scipy                    1.4.1
seaborn                  0.11.0
setuptools               41.2.0
six                      1.15.0
slacker                  0.14.0
soupsieve                2.0.1
starlette                0.12.9
tensorboard              2.3.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit   1.7.0
tensorflow               2.3.1
tensorflow-datasets      4.0.1
tensorflow-estimator     2.3.0
tensorflow-gpu-estimator 2.3.0
tensorflow-metadata      0.24.0
termcolor                1.1.0
tornado                  6.0.4
tqdm                     4.41.1
traitlets                4.3.3
typing-extensions        3.7.4.2
Unidecode                1.1.1
urllib3                  1.25.10
uvicorn                  0.11.1
wcwidth                  0.2.5
websockets               8.1
Werkzeug                 1.0.1
wheel                    0.35.1
wikiquotes               1.4
wrapt                    1.12.1
yarl                     1.5.0
zipp                     3.1.0
```

Comment: did you try pip uninstall -ensorflow-gpu ?

Comment: and did you maybe use codna to install it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname

Comment: I went through the post , there's now egg info folder associated with tensorflow , is it safe to remove ~ensorflow folder directly?