# Issue installing brownie for solidity/python

Tags: python, solidity

Ive been having issues running brownie so i uninstalled it then i reinstalled it and got the following error

> Requirement already satisfied: atomicwrites>=1.0 in
> c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from pytest==6.2.3->eth-brownie)
> (1.4.0) Requirement already satisfied: colorama in
> c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from pytest==6.2.3->eth-brownie)
> (0.4.4) Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in
> c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from web3==5.18.0->eth-brownie) (301)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p
> (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution
> -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) Installing collected
> packages: eth-brownie WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p
> (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution
> -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) Successfully installed
> eth-brownie-1.14.6 WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p
> (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution
> -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)

[image]

Comment: You might want to paste the command you ran. According to the output it says, “Successfully installed eth-brownie-1.14.6”

Comment: @BenY "pip install eth-brownie" i always see those warnings when i run brownie commands

Comment: You can verify with `pip list` to see what is in your current environment. Those warnings feel like you have some environment variables set that affecting pip and making those warnings. Looks like it has “-“ and “-p” and “-ip” in some distribution list.

Comment: @BenY updated the main post with the results after running that

Comment: Try this to get rid of those warnings  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname

Comment: @BenY i just don't know which dir to delete as none are named -p, -ip or -

Comment: The thing to note that those are warnings. The link I posted had others chiming in, and I think the directories had tildes in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way i found to fix was by uninstalling python and all packages then reinstalling it and making sure it was selected as the path in control panel -> system -> system -> advanced system setting -> environmental variables -> path

If anyone else stubbles upon this trying to fix python my advice is just to reinstall all python related stuff as its most likely something broken so save your time and start fresh