# ValueError: Image generation requires the psutil package. Install using pip: $ pip install psutil yet requirement already satisfied?

Tags: python, plotly, psutil

I am trying to save a plotly static graph using the following command:

```
graph.write_image("test.png")
```

However I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Image generation requires the psutil package.

Install using pip:
$ pip install psutil
```

However I have already done this once and receive the following trackback upon trying to install again when I have the following version of psutil

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ythonnet (c:\users\gerard\projects\venv\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ythonnet (c:\users\gerard\projects\venv\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in c:\users\gerard\projects\venv\lib\site-packages (5.8.0)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ythonnet (c:\users\gerard\projects\venv\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ythonnet (c:\users\gerard\projects\venv\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ythonnet (c:\users\gerard\projects\venv\lib\site-packages)

psutil==5.8.0
```

The `ValueError` persists everytime. Does anyone understand this or know how I can go about debugging?

Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you run `python -c "import psutil"` ?  also given the rest of the output I suspect your virtualenv is corrupted and you may want to recreate it entirely

Comment: Try searching with the warning - here is one result: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname)

Comment: @wwii I removed the -ythonnet distribution, uninstalled psutil and then reinstalled it. The `ValueError` persists

Comment: @AnthonySottile Unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: how are you running the thing which is erroring?

Comment: Looks like you are working in a virtual environment. Maybe created a new venv with your requirements then move your code over if that isn't too cumbersome. Did you check your  python\site-packages directory, do you have a *messed up* install there?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by first ensuring you have orca installed as the engine for saving the image in plotly, instead of the default kaleido. If not, this can be installed using bash:

```
conda install -c conda-forge orca
```

Next save the image with the following command `graph.write_image("test.png", engine = 'orca')`.
In case you still get an error, specify the location of orca on your machine in your script. You can find the location by running `which orca` in bash.
Then copy the found path in your python script as follows:

```
plotly.io.orca.config.executable = '/path/to/orca'
plotly.io.orca.config.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with deleting `-ythonnet` or `psutil` folder from directory `c:\users\gerard\projects\venv\lib\site-packages`. If that didn't help try with new virtual environment.