# Updating packages using pip-review doesn't work

Tags: python, pip

I tried to update all my packages using `pip-review`, which worked for me once, but now it doesn't work. When I write

```
pip-review -a
```

In the CMD, I get these errors:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\MY_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\~yzmq.libs\\libsodium-3b4bc14f.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\MY_NAME\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yrsistent (c:\users\MY_NAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ffi (c:\users\MY_NAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

I tried to open the CMD using administrator, and still the same errors. I tried to use:

```
pip-review -i
```

and update just a few packages, and not all of them together, still the same errors.

I am using python 3.9.1, nothing changed from the last time I used `pip-review` (that worked) except that I did download another version of python, python 3.8 (which I used only to run 2 pyc files).

Comment: Actually, I did, I have 2 versions of Python right now. But one of them I used only to run pyc files that were on that version only. My main version is 3.9.1 and the second one I installed is 3.8

Comment: The names in the messages seem to point at the problem: my guess is that `-ywin32` should really be `pywin32`. Does that observation ring any bells?

Comment: @BoarGules "*…my guess is that `-ywin32` should really be `pywin32`.*" Yes, they were, but they should be removed, not renamed; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56973015/7976758. Anyway these are only warnings, not errors.

Comment: After ignoring the warnings and trying to update the packages I got an `error` I have posted it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling `pip-review` and re-installing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD with administer access,
uninstall  pip-review `pip uninstall pip-review`
then

install pip-review `pip install pip-review`

Now install or update whatever you were trying and getting

```
error(WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002A478A24EB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002A478A481F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002A478A48460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002A478A486D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002A478A48940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages))
```