# How to resolve: "ContextualVersionConflict" on Python?

Tags: python, pip, numba, llvmlite, scanpy

I was trying to run scanpy's neighbors function with my genes expression dataset:

`import scanpy as sc`

`sc.pp.pca(adata)`

`sc.pp.neighbors(adata)`

and got this error:

> C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\cpu.py:77: UserWarning: Numba extension module 'sparse._numba_extension' failed to load due to 'ContextualVersionConflict((llvmlite 0.33.0+1.g022ab0f (c:\users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('llvmlite<0.38,>=0.37.0rc1'), {'numba'}))'.
> numba.core.entrypoints.init_all()

I then Tried to update my `llvmlite==0.33` version due to this error using
`pip install llvmlite --upgrade`
and got another error:

> ERROR: -umba 0.50.1 has requirement llvmlite<0.34,>=0.33.0.dev0, but you'll have llvmlite 0.37.0 which is incompatible.
> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Python doesn't let me to upgrade `llvmlite` to the newer version and therefore I cannot use scanpy's functions. I tried to update `numba`, I tried to reinstall everything, but nothing worked.

What should be done in order to solve this problem?

Comment: [Remove](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56973015/7976758) that broken `-umba`

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot! I also used: ```pip install --upgrade llvmlite --user``` in order to solve the second part of the error.