# PIP installing module gives warning but installs module

Tags: python, module, pip

I just installed pip and a module. The module installed correctly but it gives the following error.

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\python 3.8\lib\site-packages)
```

I mean to ask if this is bad or should I ignore it.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6v5Y.png

Comment: You most likely have a broken package installation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname .

Comment: I don't know which package to uninstall. Should I uninstall all the packages or is there a command to check which package is broken.

Comment: Did you read the linked question?

Comment: Yes, I did. I wrote the command "pip freeze". It only gave me a list of modules with versions. I also uninstalled recently installed modules thinking it would work but to no avail.

Comment: The linked question, or rather its answers, suggest to remove the broken package, in various ways (either with pip, or manually); see what works for you.

Comment: Hello. It worked. I found the folders starting with "~" sign and deleted them. The warning went off. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Do check whether you want to reinstall those packages properly. You can probably guess the original name, e.g. `-ip` was probably `pip`.