# cant install module named certifi

Tags: python, certifi

i tried to use this command in cmd to install module certifi:

```
pip install certifi
```

But it throws some warning like this:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

How can i fix it and install certifi ? (Python 3.9.6 )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip how to remove incorrectly installed package with a leading dash: "-pkgname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname)

Answer (score 0):

go to directory of site package and remove all files that start with tilde ~
and there is a problem with the package named `ip`

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete the following folder:

```
c:\python39\lib\site-packages\ip
```

And every file that starts with ~ and try again

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it was useful.

Comment: i tried your advance and got this :

Comment: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/certifi/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi

Comment: Try with `pip install -r requirements.txt` and please provide the output from `python --version` command.

Comment: here is the output:

Comment: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'