# import torch.fx ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.fx'

Tags: python, pytorch

After enabling torch and Cuda for my system according to my system GPU compatibility, whenever I am trying to run any program which needs to be run on GPU to enable the system, this error is coming. I could not able to find any solution for this. though I read about this that create another environment and this error will be solved but did not work for me. Please find the details of my system. for reference, I am using Python 3.7.2.

[image include torch and Cuda version and device name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzJXe.png)

[Details of NVIDIA Cuda compiler driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vnmG.png)

[nvidia-smi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJHaG.png)

Can anyone help to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

`torch.fx` was added in PyTorch 1.8.0. Check [release post](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.8-released/). You're probably using an older version. Upgrade pytorch from [website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

Comment: I think it's my environment problem after I am uninstalling a module from the current environment and then when I am going to import that module it should give me an error but it's import that particular module. what should be done?

Comment: Error is showing this message,  'WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (c:\users\subha\.conda\envs\gan\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (c:\users\subha\.conda\envs\gan\lib\site-packages)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\subha\\.conda\\envs\\gan\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.21.5.dist-info\\METADATA'

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (c:\users\subha\.conda\envs\gan\lib\site-packages)

Comment: I suggest creating a new env then install pytorch there. If you want to continue in existing env, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname

Comment: The issue also happens with `torch '1.10.0'`. As noted in another answer `from torch.fx import symbolic_trace` resolved the problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```py
import torch.fx
```

You have to import from torch.fx as below:

```py
from torch.fx import symbolic_trace
```

You can view more in the [official documentations](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/fx.html).

Comment: I have changed as you suggested but did not work. The message is showing "from torch.fx import symbolic_trace
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.fx'"

Comment: This worked for me with `torch 1.10.0`!