# How can I get rid of getting "warnings" when I use pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Whenever I try to use pip, I'm getting tons of warnings. How can I get rid of these?

For example, I tried to upgrade my pip.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install --upgrade pip
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -lrd (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etworkx (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -lrd (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etworkx (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (23.0.1)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -lrd (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etworkx (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -lrd (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etworkx (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -lrd (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etworkx (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -lrd (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etworkx (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ertifi (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

Thats the output.

I tried to upgrade my pip but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the option `-q`:

`pip install -q --upgrade pip`

According to the documentation (`pip install -h`), using the option `-q` once rids you of the warning messages, twice also rids you of the error level, and thrice also rids you of the critical level messages.

If you want to keep the warnings in a file in case you need to read them later and just don't want them in your terminal, you can use:

`pip install --upgrade pip 2> nameOfYourLog.File`

EDIT 20230409:

I'm stupid, I didn't notice you were using Windows. If you're not using cygwin or something equally unix-like, the command `pip install --upgrade pip 2> nameOfYourLog.File` won't work for you, but going by the online documentation, `pip install -q --upgrade` should still do its job.

Comment: I tried `pip install -q --upgrade pip` but still getting these errors.

Comment: @Berchister the [official site](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/) recommends the following usage for pip in a Windows environment: `py -m pip <command> [options]`, so you should try `py -m pip install -q --upgrade pip`

Comment: Actually, go check the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973015/pip-how-to-remove-incorrectly-installed-package-with-a-leading-dash-pkgname), mine simply remove the warning messages, theirs solves the underlying issue preventing you from upgrading all these packages.