# Error when installing sklearn through pip - 'metadata-generation-failed'

Tags: python, windows, scikit-learn, pip, setup.py

I'm trying to install the 'sklearn' library, using pip, but I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting sklearn
  Downloading sklearn-0.0.post4.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

I have successfully installed other packages before, like pandas for example, without having any problems.

Comment: Seeing `Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf` makes me think it is supposed to refer to `protobuf`. If I recall correctly under some conditions (during installation or upgrade), *pip* renames temporarily the directory by replacing the first letter with a dash `-`. But at the end of the process the directory should have either been renamed back to its natural name or deleted entirely. So I strongly suspect that at some point something went wrong during an installation or upgrade process. I recommend removing all `protobuf` or `-rotobuf` related directories in `site-packages` directory.

Comment: @sinoroc This is only a warning, not an error. The problem is well-known: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56973015/7976758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you install using:

```
pip install sklearn
```

do this instead:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

and in the python code you can use sklearn by `import sklearn`

Comment: It seems to have worked, thanks for the help!