Problems in installing scikit-fda
I have the pip version 22.3.1 for Python 3.10
I need to install the package scikit-fda, and I am trying to do it with
pip install scikit-fda
Unfortunately, I get error below
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fdasrsf
Failed to build fdasrsf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fdasrsf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I assume the problem might be related to
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorflow-intel (c:\users\michele\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -dasrsf (c:\users\michele\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorflow-intel (c:\users\michele\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -dasrsf (c:\users\michele\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorflow-intel (c:\users\michele\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -dasrsf (c:\users\michele\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)

How can I proceed?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

As for the "WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution" — it's only a warning. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56973015/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+WARNING%3A+Ignoring+invalid+distribution

So I've tried to install scikit-fda using pip with/without --no-cache-dir and verified the same error returns as ERROR: Failed building wheel for fdasrsf. Haven't check whether the wheel is missing or their setup.py is broken.
Alternative Solution
It worked installing scikit-fda using conda in python env.
See if you can use conda or Miniconda in the following Miniconda installation page.

Environment


python 3.10
pip 24.0
python virtual environments
ubuntu container


Verifying conda

(python) root@b01f5031453b:/# ~/miniconda3/bin/conda list
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel                                                              
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge                                                        
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge                                                        
anaconda-anon-usage       0.4.4           py312hfc0e8ea_100                                                                     
...
...
(More)


Install scikit-fda using conda


See scikit-fda GitHub README.md.
(Tip) Also, you can install from source, which is described in the README.md file.

(python) root@b01f5031453b:/# ~/miniconda3/bin/conda install -c conda-forge scikit-fda
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 
done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /root/miniconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - scikit-fda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _libgcc_mutex-0.1          |      conda_forge           3 KB  conda-forge
    _openmp_mutex-4.5          |            2_gnu          23 KB  conda-forge
    brotli-1.1.0               |       hd590300_1          19 KB  conda-forge
    brotli-bin-1.1.0           |       hd590300_1          19 KB  conda-forge
    certifi-2024.2.2           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         157 KB  conda-forge
    conda-24.3.0               |  py312h7900ff3_0         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    contourpy-1.2.1            |  py312h8572e83_0         251 KB  conda-forge
    cycler-0.12.1              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          13 KB  conda-forge
    cython-3.0.10              |  py312h30efb56_0         3.6 MB  conda-forge
    dcor-0.6                   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          43 KB  conda-forge
    fdasrsf-2.5.10             |  py312hfb8ada1_0         574 KB  conda-forge
    findiff-0.10.0             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          32 KB  conda-forge
    fonttools-4.51.0           |  py312h98912ed_0         2.7 MB  conda-forge
    freetype-2.12.1            |       h267a509_2         620 KB  conda-forge
    importlib-metadata-7.1.0   |     pyha770c72_0          26 KB  conda-forge
    joblib-1.4.0               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         215 KB  conda-forge
    kiwisolver-1.4.5           |  py312h8572e83_1          70 KB  conda-forge
    lazy_loader-0.4            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          16 KB  conda-forge
    lcms2-2.16                 |       hb7c19ff_0         239 KB  conda-forge
    lerc-4.0.0                 |       h27087fc_0         275 KB  conda-forge
    libblas-3.9.0              |22_linux64_openblas          14 KB  conda-forge
    libbrotlicommon-1.1.0      |       hd590300_1          68 KB  conda-forge
    libbrotlidec-1.1.0         |       hd590300_1          32 KB  conda-forge
    libbrotlienc-1.1.0         |       hd590300_1         276 KB  conda-forge
    libcblas-3.9.0             |22_linux64_openblas          14 KB  conda-forge
    libdeflate-1.20            |       hd590300_0          70 KB  conda-forge
    libexpat-2.5.0             |       hcb278e6_1          76 KB  conda-forge
    libgcc-ng-13.2.0           |       h807b86a_5         752 KB  conda-forge
    libgfortran-ng-13.2.0      |       h69a702a_5          23 KB  conda-forge
    libgfortran5-13.2.0        |       ha4646dd_5         1.4 MB  conda-forge
    libgomp-13.2.0             |       h807b86a_5         410 KB  conda-forge
    libjpeg-turbo-3.0.0        |       hd590300_1         604 KB  conda-forge
    liblapack-3.9.0            |22_linux64_openblas          14 KB  conda-forge
    libllvm14-14.0.6           |       hcd5def8_4        30.0 MB  conda-forge
    libnsl-2.0.1               |       hd590300_0          33 KB  conda-forge
    libopenblas-0.3.27         |pthreads_h413a1c8_0         5.3 MB  conda-forge
    libpng-1.6.43              |       h2797004_0         281 KB  conda-forge
    libsqlite-3.45.3           |       h2797004_0         840 KB  conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng-13.2.0        |       h7e041cc_5         3.7 MB  conda-forge
    libtiff-4.6.0              |       h1dd3fc0_3         276 KB  conda-forge
    libuuid-2.38.1             |       h0b41bf4_0          33 KB  conda-forge
    libwebp-base-1.4.0         |       hd590300_0         429 KB  conda-forge
    libxcb-1.15                |       h0b41bf4_0         375 KB  conda-forge
    libxcrypt-4.4.36           |       hd590300_1          98 KB  conda-forge
    libzlib-1.2.13             |       hd590300_5          60 KB  conda-forge
    llvmlite-0.42.0            |  py312hb06c811_1         3.2 MB  conda-forge
    matplotlib-base-3.8.4      |  py312he5832f3_0         7.4 MB  conda-forge
    mpmath-1.3.0               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         428 KB  conda-forge
    multimethod-1.9.1          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    munkres-1.1.4              |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          12 KB  conda-forge
    numba-0.59.1               |  py312hacefee8_0         5.4 MB  conda-forge
    numpy-1.26.4               |  py312heda63a1_0         7.1 MB  conda-forge
    openjpeg-2.5.2             |       h488ebb8_0         334 KB  conda-forge
    openssl-3.2.1              |       hd590300_1         2.7 MB  conda-forge
    pandas-2.2.2               |  py312hfb8ada1_0        14.7 MB  conda-forge
    patsy-0.5.6                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         183 KB  conda-forge
    pillow-10.3.0              |  py312hdcec9eb_0        40.0 MB  conda-forge
    pthread-stubs-0.4          |    h36c2ea0_1001           5 KB  conda-forge
    pyparsing-3.1.2            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          87 KB  conda-forge
    python-3.12.2              |hab00c5b_0_cpython        30.8 MB  conda-forge
    python-dateutil-2.9.0      |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         218 KB  conda-forge
    python-tzdata-2024.1       |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         141 KB  conda-forge
    python_abi-3.12            |          4_cp312           6 KB  conda-forge
    pytz-2024.1                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         184 KB  conda-forge
    rdata-0.11.2               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          41 KB  conda-forge
    scikit-datasets-0.2.4      |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          40 KB  conda-forge
    scikit-fda-0.9.1           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         274 KB  conda-forge
    scikit-learn-1.4.2         |  py312h394d371_0         9.7 MB  conda-forge
    scipy-1.13.0               |  py312heda63a1_0        16.6 MB  conda-forge
    six-1.16.0                 |     pyh6c4a22f_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    sympy-1.12                 |     pyh04b8f61_3         4.0 MB  conda-forge
    threadpoolctl-3.4.0        |     pyhc1e730c_0          22 KB  conda-forge
    tk-8.6.13                  |noxft_h4845f30_101         3.2 MB  conda-forge
    typing-extensions-4.11.0   |       hd8ed1ab_0          10 KB  conda-forge
    typing_extensions-4.11.0   |     pyha770c72_0          37 KB  conda-forge
    xarray-2024.3.0            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         747 KB  conda-forge
    xorg-libxau-1.0.11         |       hd590300_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3        |       h7f98852_0          19 KB  conda-forge
    zipp-3.17.0                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          19 KB  conda-forge
    zlib-1.2.13                |       hd590300_5          91 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       202.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  brotli             conda-forge/linux-64::brotli-1.1.0-hd590300_1 
  brotli-bin         conda-forge/linux-64::brotli-bin-1.1.0-hd590300_1 
  contourpy          conda-forge/linux-64::contourpy-1.2.1-py312h8572e83_0 
  cycler             conda-forge/noarch::cycler-0.12.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  cython             conda-forge/linux-64::cython-3.0.10-py312h30efb56_0 
  dcor               conda-forge/noarch::dcor-0.6-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  fdasrsf            conda-forge/linux-64::fdasrsf-2.5.10-py312hfb8ada1_0 
  findiff            conda-forge/noarch::findiff-0.10.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  fonttools          conda-forge/linux-64::fonttools-4.51.0-py312h98912ed_0 
  freetype           conda-forge/linux-64::freetype-2.12.1-h267a509_2 
  importlib-metadata conda-forge/noarch::importlib-metadata-7.1.0-pyha770c72_0 
  joblib             conda-forge/noarch::joblib-1.4.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  kiwisolver         conda-forge/linux-64::kiwisolver-1.4.5-py312h8572e83_1 
  lazy_loader        conda-forge/noarch::lazy_loader-0.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  lcms2              conda-forge/linux-64::lcms2-2.16-hb7c19ff_0 
  lerc               conda-forge/linux-64::lerc-4.0.0-h27087fc_0 
  libblas            conda-forge/linux-64::libblas-3.9.0-22_linux64_openblas 
  libbrotlicommon    conda-forge/linux-64::libbrotlicommon-1.1.0-hd590300_1 
  libbrotlidec       conda-forge/linux-64::libbrotlidec-1.1.0-hd590300_1 
  libbrotlienc       conda-forge/linux-64::libbrotlienc-1.1.0-hd590300_1 
  libcblas           conda-forge/linux-64::libcblas-3.9.0-22_linux64_openblas 
  libdeflate         conda-forge/linux-64::libdeflate-1.20-hd590300_0 
  libexpat           conda-forge/linux-64::libexpat-2.5.0-hcb278e6_1 
  libgfortran-ng     conda-forge/linux-64::libgfortran-ng-13.2.0-h69a702a_5 
  libgfortran5       conda-forge/linux-64::libgfortran5-13.2.0-ha4646dd_5 
  libjpeg-turbo      conda-forge/linux-64::libjpeg-turbo-3.0.0-hd590300_1 
  liblapack          conda-forge/linux-64::liblapack-3.9.0-22_linux64_openblas 
  libllvm14          conda-forge/linux-64::libllvm14-14.0.6-hcd5def8_4 
  libnsl             conda-forge/linux-64::libnsl-2.0.1-hd590300_0 
  libopenblas        conda-forge/linux-64::libopenblas-0.3.27-pthreads_h413a1c8_0 
  libpng             conda-forge/linux-64::libpng-1.6.43-h2797004_0 
  libsqlite          conda-forge/linux-64::libsqlite-3.45.3-h2797004_0 
  libtiff            conda-forge/linux-64::libtiff-4.6.0-h1dd3fc0_3 
  libwebp-base       conda-forge/linux-64::libwebp-base-1.4.0-hd590300_0 
  libxcb             conda-forge/linux-64::libxcb-1.15-h0b41bf4_0 
  libxcrypt          conda-forge/linux-64::libxcrypt-4.4.36-hd590300_1 
  libzlib            conda-forge/linux-64::libzlib-1.2.13-hd590300_5 
  llvmlite           conda-forge/linux-64::llvmlite-0.42.0-py312hb06c811_1 
  matplotlib-base    conda-forge/linux-64::matplotlib-base-3.8.4-py312he5832f3_0 
  mpmath             conda-forge/noarch::mpmath-1.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  multimethod        conda-forge/noarch::multimethod-1.9.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  munkres            conda-forge/noarch::munkres-1.1.4-pyh9f0ad1d_0 
  numba              conda-forge/linux-64::numba-0.59.1-py312hacefee8_0 
  numpy              conda-forge/linux-64::numpy-1.26.4-py312heda63a1_0 
  openjpeg           conda-forge/linux-64::openjpeg-2.5.2-h488ebb8_0 
  pandas             conda-forge/linux-64::pandas-2.2.2-py312hfb8ada1_0 
  patsy              conda-forge/noarch::patsy-0.5.6-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pillow             conda-forge/linux-64::pillow-10.3.0-py312hdcec9eb_0 
  pthread-stubs      conda-forge/linux-64::pthread-stubs-0.4-h36c2ea0_1001 
  pyparsing          conda-forge/noarch::pyparsing-3.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  python-dateutil    conda-forge/noarch::python-dateutil-2.9.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  python-tzdata      conda-forge/noarch::python-tzdata-2024.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  python_abi         conda-forge/linux-64::python_abi-3.12-4_cp312 
  pytz               conda-forge/noarch::pytz-2024.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  rdata              conda-forge/noarch::rdata-0.11.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  scikit-datasets    conda-forge/noarch::scikit-datasets-0.2.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  scikit-fda         conda-forge/noarch::scikit-fda-0.9.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  scikit-learn       conda-forge/linux-64::scikit-learn-1.4.2-py312h394d371_0 
  scipy              conda-forge/linux-64::scipy-1.13.0-py312heda63a1_0 
  six                conda-forge/noarch::six-1.16.0-pyh6c4a22f_0 
  sympy              conda-forge/noarch::sympy-1.12-pyh04b8f61_3 
  threadpoolctl      conda-forge/noarch::threadpoolctl-3.4.0-pyhc1e730c_0 
  typing-extensions  conda-forge/noarch::typing-extensions-4.11.0-hd8ed1ab_0 
  typing_extensions  conda-forge/noarch::typing_extensions-4.11.0-pyha770c72_0 
  xarray             conda-forge/noarch::xarray-2024.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  xorg-libxau        conda-forge/linux-64::xorg-libxau-1.0.11-hd590300_0 
  xorg-libxdmcp      conda-forge/linux-64::xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3-h7f98852_0 
  zipp               conda-forge/noarch::zipp-3.17.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  libgcc-ng          pkgs/main::libgcc-ng-11.2.0-h1234567_1 --> conda-forge::libgcc-ng-13.2.0-h807b86a_5 
  libgomp              pkgs/main::libgomp-11.2.0-h1234567_1 --> conda-forge::libgomp-13.2.0-h807b86a_5 
  libstdcxx-ng       pkgs/main::libstdcxx-ng-11.2.0-h12345~ --> conda-forge::libstdcxx-ng-13.2.0-h7e041cc_5 
  libuuid              pkgs/main::libuuid-1.41.5-h5eee18b_0 --> conda-forge::libuuid-2.38.1-h0b41bf4_0 
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-3.0.13-h7f8727e_0 --> conda-forge::openssl-3.2.1-hd590300_1 
  tk                        pkgs/main::tk-8.6.12-h1ccaba5_0 --> conda-forge::tk-8.6.13-noxft_h4845f30_101 
  zlib                    pkgs/main::zlib-1.2.13-h5eee18b_0 --> conda-forge::zlib-1.2.13-hd590300_5 

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  _libgcc_mutex           pkgs/main::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main --> conda-forge::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-conda_forge 
  _openmp_mutex          pkgs/main::_openmp_mutex-5.1-1_gnu --> conda-forge::_openmp_mutex-4.5-2_gnu 
  certifi            pkgs/main/linux-64::certifi-2024.2.2-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2024.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  conda              pkgs/main::conda-24.3.0-py312h06a4308~ --> conda-forge::conda-24.3.0-py312h7900ff3_0 
  python                pkgs/main::python-3.12.2-h996f2a0_0 --> conda-forge::python-3.12.2-hab00c5b_0_cpython 


Proceed ([y]/n)? 

Downloading and Extracting Packages:
                                                                                                                                
Preparing transaction: done                                                                                                     
Verifying transaction: done                                                                                                     
Executing transaction: done


Verified scikit-fda is installed

(python) root@b01f5031453b:/# ~/miniconda3/bin/conda list | grep scikit-fda
scikit-fda                0.9.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

